# Cucumber embed for screenshots not linking to screenshot

Tags: ruby, cucumber, embed, watir, watir-webdriver

Cross-posted from the Cukes Google Group:

I have experimented with a number of methods of saving screenshots,
but settled on the method that is built into watir-webdriver.  No
matter which method I have used, I am not able to successfully embed a
link to this image in the Cucumber HTML report.

In c:\ruby\cucumber\project_name\features\support\hooks.rb, I'm using:

```
After do |scenario|
   if scenario.failed?
      @browser.driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")
      embed("screenshot.png", "image/png")
   end
end
```

A link with text "Screenshot" IS added to the report, but the URL is
the project directory path `("c:\ruby\cucumber\project_name")` rather
than a direct link to the file `("c:\ruby\cucumber\project_name\screenshot.png")`.  I have tried a number of different image formats
and direct paths using Dir.pwd with the same results each time.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Windows XP
Ruby 1.8.7
watir-webdriver (0.2.4)
cucumber (0.10.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aslak:

> Try this:

```
After do |scenario|
  if scenario.failed?
    encoded_img = @browser.driver.screenshot_as(:base64)
    embed("data:image/png;base64,#{encoded_img}",'image/png')
  end
end
```

> Aslak

Adam:

> Aslak was able to see the embedded
>   image in the file that I emailed him,
>   while I was still unable to do so in
>   IE 8.  I tried it out in Firefox 3.6
>   and the image appears as expected. 
>   The problem may have originally been
>   with the embedding method itself (or
>   rather, my use of it), but using
>   Aslak's base64 solution it only fails
>   to work in the Internet Explorer
>   browser.

Aslak:

> I believe Base64-encoding of images in
>   HTML pages [1] works in all decent
>   browsers (sorry, IE is not one of
>   them). However, it *should* work in
>   IE:
>   http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/06/base64-ie/
>   (but maybe they broke it in IE8, or
>   maybe it only works with gifs, or
>   maybe IE needs a *special* kind of
>   base64 encoding, or maybe you should
>   just ditch IE)
>
> If being able to read cucumber html
>   reports with screenshots in IE is
>   really important to you, you could
>   always write each image to disk:

```
 png = @browser.driver.screenshot_as(:png)
 path = (0..16).to_a.map{|a| rand(16).to_s(16)}.join + '.png' # Or use some GUID library to make a unique filename - scenario names are not  guaranteed to be unique.
 File.open(path, 'wb') {|io| io.write(png)}
 embed(path, 'image/png')
```

> Obviously you have to make sure the
>   relative path you pass to embed is
>   right (depending on where you write
>   the html itself)
>
> [1]
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme
>
> HTH, Aslak

Comment: IE is still one of the most popular browsers.  As testers we need to test what the users are using, not just what we personally approve of or consider to be 'decent'

Comment: An important point Chuck, but in this case we are talking only about reading (not building) reports. IE# is fully testable, but reading the output when using the base64 image embed approach does not currently work.

Comment: with regard to generating the name, this blog posting has some nice logic for that, and neatly handles scenario outlines as well.  http://twofourone.blogspot.com/2011/04/making-your-cukes-more-awesomer-with.html