# Remote Screenshot with selenium aplies a strong black layer over some elements

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, screenshot

I'm taking screenshots with selenium from a remote server. When the screenshots are taken from my local computer, everything works fine. But some of the screenshots from the remote server are coming with a dark black shadow over some elements.

[here is how the screenshot looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF2a5.png)

In the black area must have some content. And after changing some color properties, we can see that the content is there actually. The weirdness in my opinion, is the fact that some elements are just fine. I already tried to increase the wait before taking the screenshot and the method used for(selenium has more than one method for taking screenshots).

```
self.driver.set_window_size(self.width, total_height)
timefrommoduletime.sleep(self.minimum_sleep_between_actions + 5) 
self.driver.save_screenshot(path)
```

Comment: Perhaps the problem is related to your server environment. Can you provide more details on that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963045/selenium-2-webdriver-taking-a-screenshot-returns-a-black-image

Comment: In the server is running a container that uses "selenium/standalone-chrome:3.141.59-20200409"